# Can I create Magento connect extension from angularJS code?

Tags: extensions, javascript

I have a webwidget written in angularJS. I can load the webwidget in Magento site by embedding a small java script that loads the angularJS code that is deployed on a central CMS. Now I want to package this module into Magento connect extension and publish it Magento market place. Can this be done and how or do I need to write the entire module in PHP before creating it into extension archive?

Comment: Interestingly enough the Magento 2 web installation process uses Angular.

Answer (score 0):

At the minimum you will still need to create Magento module or theme, so that you can insert the block file that can inject the Angular.js frontend code (those Javascripts and CSS) or just the loader javascript to pull your Angular.js code.

If the code involve Magento API, then it will be more complex, you may need to look into method renderer stuff as part Magento module as well.

Hope that helps,